# my model date type is only Date but i get Datetime in Laravel

Tags: laravel, date, datetime-format

i need to get only date from my date filed and date filed type is DATE but i get date and time in Laravel :

my value saved in sql:1970-04-21
value i get:1970-04-21 00:00:00

```
<?php

 namespace App\Models;

 use App\Models\Scopes\Searchable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Date extends Model
{
use HasFactory;
use Searchable;
use SoftDeletes;

protected $fillable = ['date'];

protected $searchableFields = ['*'];

protected $casts = [
    'date' => 'date',
];
 }
```

this this my controller :

```
 public function index(Request $request): View
{
    $this->authorize('view-any', Date::class);

    $search = $request->get('search', '');

    $dates = Date::search($search)
        ->latest()
        ->paginate(5)
        ->withQueryString();

    return view('app.dates.index', compact('dates', 'search'));
}
```

Comment: try casting with format `'date' => 'datetime:Y-m-d'`

Comment: still i get 1970-04-21 00:00:00

Comment: maybe `'date' => 'date:Y-m-d'`

Comment: no change:1970-04-21 00:00:00

Comment: just did some test and it works perfectly fine `'created_at' => 'date:Y-m-d'` output is `created_at: "2023-01-03",` 

try clearing your cache and test the other date field like created_at or updated_at

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change format of date when you get the date try to use `accessor`

```
  <?php

 namespace App\Models;

 use App\Models\Scopes\Searchable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Date extends Model
{
use HasFactory;
use Searchable;
use SoftDeletes;

protected $fillable = ['date'];

protected $searchableFields = ['*'];

public function getDateAttribute($value)
    {
        return $this->asDateTime($value)->format('Y-m-d');
    }
 }
```